# SharePoint 2013 Permission/Rights Requirement for Service Accounts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, administration

We have an internal review to verify what DB permission/rights should be assigned to different users in SQL. Please help us determining the SQL server permissions/rights required for different service accounts for a SharePoint 2013 farm installation:

```
Service Accounts    Permission Required(in SQL Server, and to what databases)
sa                    ?
SP Farm               ?
SQL Admin             ?
Farm Service account  ?
SP Search Account     ?
```

I have gone through [Technet Article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14500.sharepoint-2013-service-accounts.aspx) but it does't give any information on rights required at SQL side, suppose accidentally anyone has updated/removed any rights then how can we assign back the required rights. Any useful links describing the permission would be helpful.

Thanks,

Deepak Semwal

Answer (score 0):

Remember that modifying SP database permissions is not supported. Maybe that's the reason why there is not much info about it.

If you have build a farm, I would take a script of the permission schema in SQL Server.

Regards